# Rake test output in Win (dots instead of tests)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When I run rake test under Windows, I see dots instead of test names. All tests pass fine, though. Output example:

```
>rake test
# Running tests:
. . . . . . .
Finished tests in <...>
7 test, 10 alterations, 0 errors, 0 failures, 0 skips
```

And `test/unit/product_test.erb` contents:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'product attributes must not be empty' do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end
end
```

Rails version: 3.2.1, Ruby version: 1.9.3

Didn't find anything helpful. Would be grateful for any suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got back to this question after a while. All I needed - 'turn' gem. And a 'minitest' to work with it.

Added this to Gemfile and my output became prettier...